# Getting data of ground water quality for spatially map for demonstration purpose?

Tags: data

I need some arbitary data of ground water quality for demonstration purpose or for analysis in qgis.

Can some body tell me where i can get these data easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your data requirements, it is a bit difficult to point you to the correct place. However to answer your question generically, the USGS provides water quality data through there water quality data portal [here](http://www.waterqualitydata.us/) there are additional data sources as well if you go to the main USGS water quality page [here](http://water.usgs.gov/owq/data.html).

In terms of India, the government provides water quality data [here](https://data.gov.in/dataset-group-name/water-quality).

Comment: I need chlorine concentration data of each specific location for a city of west bengal, India